# Android TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech, activity-lifecycle

My TextToSpeech works fine on the first run, but it doesn't work after the application has been closed using "back" key and reopened. The error is `TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine` and `status` in `onInit` is `ERROR`

I have a class to handle TTS:

```
public class VoiceGenerator {
    public TextToSpeech tts;
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "Voice Generator";

    private static VoiceGenerator instance;

    private VoiceGenerator(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static VoiceGenerator getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VoiceGenerator(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void initializeTTS() {
        if (tts == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "initialize tts");
            tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "initialize tts success");
                        tts.setLanguage(...);                           
                    }      
                }
            });    
        }
    }

    public void speak(){
        tts.speak(...)
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        if(tts != null) {   
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
            tts=null;
            Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
        }
    }

}
```

I get the instance of VoiceGenerator in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    voiceGenerator = VoiceGenerator.getInstance(this);
}
```

Initialize TTS in onStart:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    voiceGenerator.initializeTTS();
}
```

And shut it down in onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
voiceGenerator.shutdown();    
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` on the `MainActivity`.
Here's a good example.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    private TextToSpeech engine;
    private EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        engine = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }



    public void speakText(View v) {

        String textContents = text.getText().toString();
        engine.speak(textContents, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {


        if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            //Setting speech Language
            engine.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            engine.setPitch(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what if the initialization fails?

Answer (score 1):

Use onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution , not all devices support TextToSpeach  , try with different devices, an

Answer (score -1):

You can only let the engine speak, after onInit is done, so do following in onInit():

```
   if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
     tts.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);      

   }
```

Comment: The problem is that status is ERROR so this doesn't help.